# STOP: c000021a, Status 0xc000026c

Tags: windows-server-2003, bsod

After rebooting my Server 2003 cause of an Windows update, if got the following BSOD.

Neither "safe mode" or "last good known configuration" nor checkdisk working.

Cause this error could have be much different reasons, this thread should collect much solutions als possible.

Please only post answers regarding:

```
STOP:c000021a {Fatal System Error} 
The Session Manager Initialization system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0xc000026c
```

german error (for Google search)

```
STOP: c000021a {Schwerer Systemfehler}
Der Systemprozess Session Manager Initialization wurde unerwartet beendet. Status 0xc000026c (0x00000000 0x00000000).
Das System wurde heruntergefahren.
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  That's not how this site works.  [Take a moment to visit the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), and maybe browse around a bit to get a better idea of what this site is all about.

Comment: oh, sorry, could you formulate my question that it match the ServerFault guidelines? otherwise please delete. but this solution seems not found anywhere else on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating into this error, I found that KB2761226 overwrites some essential system files:

```
83.328: Source:C:\WINDOWS\system32\SET8.tmp (5.2.3790.5079)
83.328: Destination:C:\WINDOWS\system32\win32k.sys (5.2.3790.5032)
```

After replacing the win32k.sys with an old version (simply search your windows drive, there are some backups) the system will boot an running fine.